# Two project that needs the same library

Tags: angular, design-patterns

I have this project that I decided to create an external controls library for, until now I've been creating controls inside the main project but its getting cramped up in that project, and a library could be useful for future projects, but I still need bootstrap in the main project.

The thing is I am mainly using `ng-bootstrap` for the controls, if I do separate the controls into a controls library is there a way to provide `ng-bootstrap` to the controls library, from the main project, and if so, how can I do that ?

If not, what is the best practice for this ?

And is installing `ng-bootstrap` in both project a good idea ? It doesn't feel right to do so.

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of peerDependecies as Angular does in Librarys:

> Angular libraries should list any @angular/* dependencies the library depends on as peer dependencies. This ensures that when modules ask for Angular, they all get the exact same module. If a library lists @angular/core in dependencies instead of peerDependencies, it might get a different Angular module instead, which would cause your application to break.
>
> https://angular.io/guide/creating-libraries#use-typescript-path-mapping-for-peer-dependencies

But often you don't directly `require` or `import` such dependencies within your library:

> In some cases, you want to express the compatibility of your package with a host tool or library, while not necessarily doing a require of this host. This is usually referred to as a plugin. Notably, your module may be exposing a specific interface, expected and specified by the host documentation.
>
> https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/configuring-npm/package-json#peerdependencies

So I'd say in your case it would also be fine if you depend on the package from both, the host and the library. Especially if you want to reuse the library later and the host does not use ng-bootstrap initially.